# gnuplot: plotting a file with 4 columns all on y-axis

Tags: gnuplot, curve

I have a file that contains 4 numbers (min, max, mean, standard derivation) and I would like to plot it with gnuplot.

Sample:

```
24 31 29.0909 2.57451
12 31 27.2727 5.24129
14 31 26.1818 5.04197
22 31 27.7273 3.13603
22 31 28.1818 2.88627
```

If I have 4 files with one column, then I can do:

```
gnuplot "file1.txt" with lines, "file2.txt" with lines, "file3.txt" with lines, "file4.txt" with lines
```

And it will plot 4 curves. I do not care about the x-axis, it should just be a constant increment.

How do I plot them? I can't seem to find a way to have 4 curves with 1 file with 4 columns, just having a constantly incrementing x value.

Comment: One way I thought of doing, is to put an incremental count on the left, and then use using 1:2, using 1:3.... but maybe there is a way without the extra column please?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can plot different columns of the same file like this:

```
plot 'file' using 0:1 with lines, '' using 0:2 with lines ...
```

(`...` means continuation). A couple of notes on this notation: `using` specifies which column to plot i.e. column 0 and 1 in the first `using` statement, the 0th column is a pseudo column that translates to the current line number in the data file. Note that if only one argument is used with `using` (e.g. `using n`) it corresponds to saying `using 0:n` (thanks for pointing that out *mgilson*).

If your Gnuplot version is recent enough, you would be able to plot all 4 columns with a for-loop:

```
set key outside
plot for [col=1:4] 'file' using 0:col with lines
```

Result:

[image: for-loop plot]

Gnuplot can use column headings for the title if they are in the data file, e.g.:

```
min max mean std
24 31 29.0909 2.57451
12 31 27.2727 5.24129
14 31 26.1818 5.04197
22 31 27.7273 3.13603
22 31 28.1818 2.88627
```

and

```
set key outside
plot for [col=1:4] 'file' using 0:col with lines title columnheader
```

Results in:

[image: for-loop plot with column headers]

Comment: I believe that the `0` is unnecessary actually ... `plot for [col=1:4] 'foo' using col` -- This is just a FYI.  I actually prefer the script with it in there.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect, very insightful. Helped me a lot!

Comment: I think it is rather unintutive. Anybody knows why the gnuplot syntax is so unexpressive?

Comment: @ajoy general data plotting is complex and needs a full language to do it well. But most tools, including gnuplot, want to just make plots not a language (and end up with a half-baked language anyways)

Answer (score 14):

Just to add that you can specify the increment in the for loop as third argument. It is useful if you want to plot every nth column.

```
plot for [col=START:END:INC] 'file' using col with lines
```

In this case it changes nothing but anyway:

```
plot for [col=1:4:1] 'file' using col with lines
```